# Access intermediate (and final) model transformation of a GridSearch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

Say I have a sklearn pipeline:

```
A(X) -> B(A(X)) -> C(B(A(X)))

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid)
```

I run a gridsearch over hyperparameters to find the best model. Is there built in functionality to output the intermediate and finals steps of the model? I suppose I could re-run the pipeline with the discovered best parameters on the same data, and results of each step, but perhaps this already exists, as something like:

```
grid_search.best_params.X_output_()
```

or

```
grid_search.step_A.output_()
```

My end goal is to visualise how the discovered best parameters influence the input data `X` at each transformation step.

Comment: No, this doesn't exist. There is [some functionality of caching](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#caching-transformers-avoid-repeated-computation) internal transformers of pipeline, but since the GridSearchCV will divide the data into multiple parts (according to the `cv` param), I dont see if that (or any other thing you want) can be useful here.

Comment: The best parameters are found from the average performance of those parameters over different folds of data. So trying to visualize those things would not be easy. You are better off re-running the pipeline on the data that you want to see (which may or may not be the same data)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need `cv_results_`:

---

**Toy example:**

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
svc = svm.SVC()
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)


clf.cv_results_
```

You can have access to the following information:

```
sorted(clf.cv_results_.keys())
```

> ['mean_fit_time',  'mean_score_time',  'mean_test_score', 
>   'mean_train_score',  'param_C',  'param_kernel',  'params', 
>   'rank_test_score',  'split0_test_score',  'split0_train_score', 
>   'split1_test_score',  'split1_train_score',  'split2_test_score', 
>   'split2_train_score',  'std_fit_time',  'std_score_time', 
>   'std_test_score',  'std_train_score']

Comment: this only contains scores and timings of the gridsearch, rather than transformed input data

Comment: this is true. I see only one way to do what you want. Do it manually by splitting the data and then use loops for the parameter grid search.